# bootstrap: collapse-group within collapse-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, collapsable

I've used the example from [jsfiddle 68RXP](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/68RXP/) `collapse-group` to create an expandable div:

HTML:

```
<div class="span4 collapse-group">
     <h2>Heading</h2>
     <p class="collapse">Lorem ipsum</p>
     <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.row .btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
    $collapse.collapse('toggle');
});
```

When `btn` is pressed, the `p` class is toggled between expanded and collapsed mode.

I've tried to use the same concept for recursive collapsible divs:

```
<div class="collapse-group">
    <p><a class="btn" href="#">Open outer div &raquo;</a></p>
    <div class="collapse">
        <h2>Outer div title</h2>
        <p>Outer div text</p>
        <div class="collapse-group">
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">Open inner div &raquo;</a></p>
            <div class="collapse">
                <h2>Inner div title</h2>
                <p>Inner div text</p>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same js code as before, see [jsFiddle WdbUe](http://jsfiddle.net/adamatan/WdbUe/3/).

When opening the outer collapsible div for the first time, the inner div is opened as well. **How do I couple each `expand` button to a single collapsible div?**

Answer (score 4):

I've used `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#some_id"` and a distinct id for every collapsible `div`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <h2>Bootstrap-jQuery collapse example</h2>
        <p>Based on <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/68RXP/">fiddle 68RXP</a></p>  
        <div class="collapse-group">
            <p><a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoout">Open outer div &raquo;</a></p>
            <div class="collapse in" id="demoout">
                <h1>Outer div title</h1>
                <p>Outer div text</p>

                <div class="collapse-group">
                    <p><a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoin">Open inner div &raquo;</a></p>
                    <div class="collapse in"  id="demoin">
                        <h2>Inner div title</h2>
                        <p>Inner div text</p>

                     <div class="collapse-group">
                    <p><a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoinin">Open inner div &raquo;</a></p>
                    <div class="collapse in"  id="demoinin">
                        <h3>Inner-inner div title</h3>
                        <p>Inner-inner div text</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>    
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this `js` code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".collapse").collapse();
});
```

Working example: [jsfiddle K63P3](http://jsfiddle.net/adamatan/K63P3/5/)

Credit: [aximay@jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aximay/155/edit).